# Interpretation of Modularity in R

Tags: r, clustering, networks, modularity

I used modularity maximization cluster method to make 3 different clusters (4, 5 and 6 clusters) from a network using "Igraph" in R. I found the modularity of the three networks are 0.15, 0.23, and 0.3 respectively. How can I Interpret this result?

I know modularity is a measure of strength; how well the node in each community/cluster is bonded to each other.

From my result can I tell that 
1)cluster 6 has the most strong bond among them?
2)With the increase of the number of clusters, the modularity will also increase?